# PowerShell - Rename file to the name of the folder in which it is located

Tags: powershell

I don't know if this would be best done in PowerShell, but basically I have a lot of movies with names that are incorrect. The folder name for each movie is correct however.

Within a folder, I want to go through each folder and rename an .mp4 file to the same name as the folder.

Each folder has only an .mp4 file in it and a .jpg file, but I want to rename *just* the .mp4 file (although renaming both really wouldn't be bad either.)

Is there a simple way to do this in PowerShell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A readable version:

```
Get-ChildItem -Attributes Directory D:\Videos | ForEach-Object {
    Get-ChildItem -Path $_ *.mp4 | Rename-Item -NewName "$_.mp4"
}
```

The first `Get-ChildItem` gets all the directory objects within `D:\Videos` and `ForEach-Object` iterates over each of those directories as `$_` in the following block.

Inside the block, `Get-ChildItem` is used again to get an `mp4` file from the given directory via the `-Path` option.  Finally, `Rename-Item` is used to rename the video file without moving it from its current directory.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
# run from your D:\Movies (or whatever) folder

# Go through all subfolders of the folder we're currently in, and find all of the .MP4 
# files.  For each .MP4 file we find...
ls -Recurse -Filter *.mp4 | %{ 
    # Get the full path to the MP4 file; use it to find the name of the parent folder.
    # $_ represents the .MP4 file that we're currently working on.
    # Split-Path with the -Parent switch will give us the full path to the parent 
    # folder.  Cast that path to a System.IO.DirectoryInfo object, and get the 
    # Name property, which is just the name of the folder.  
    # There are other (maybe better) ways to do this, this is just the way I chose.
    $name = ([IO.DirectoryInfo](Split-Path $_.FullName -Parent)).Name

    # Tell the user what we're doing...
    Write-Host "Renaming $_ to $($name).mp4..."

    # Rename the file.
    # We have to provide the full path to the file we're renaming, so we use
    # $_.FullName to get it.  The new name of the file is the same as that of the
    # parent folder, which we stored in $name.
    # We also remember to add the .MP4 file extension back to the name.
    Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName "$($name).mp4"
}
```

Comment: This worked great. Thanks, Mind explaining how it works exactly (helps me understand better)

Comment: I would struggle to give a more detailed description than the comments, but I _can_ comment and say this is excellent and does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a cross version example:

```
Get-ChildItem D:\temp\*\*.mp4 | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Directory.Name +'.mp4'}
```